# How to rewrite this on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ul with 5 li inside, need to select one of them with index [curSlide-1], I writed it on JS, but can't do that on jQuery:

```
var $bullets = $("ul").find(".bullet");
var curSlide = 5;

document.getElementsByClassName("bullet")[curSlide-1].className = "bullet active-bullet";
```

I've tried to write it on jQuery, but it doesn't work:

```
$bullets[curSlide-1].addClass("active-bullet");
```

Can somebody tell how to rewrite it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$.eq()` function.

You can see the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$('ul .bullet').eq(curSlide-1).addClass('active-bullet');
```

Comment: A nice use of the eq(); method, which most devs seem to forget.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need)